# String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, stringbuilder

While looking for a solution to this I found a suggestion to use sc.next() instead of sc.nextLine() but I can't use that so I require additional assistance.

I Am developing an online multiplayer text game and need to filter player name but I keep getting the error "String index out of range: 0" I have tried for hours to fix this and have not been able to find a solution.
The Function causing the error is this:

```
public static Player charCreate(Player player) {

    int points = 60;
    int i = 0;
    boolean cont = true;
    int str = 0;
    int dex = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int INT = 0;
    int lck = 0;
    int cha = 0;

    Output.slowDiscription("You stand there and think about all"
            + " that has transpired, who are you realy?");

    System.out.print("What is your Name? ");

    boolean bool = false;
    String temp;
    String name = null; //name is forced to be declared by while loop

    do {

        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(name);
        if (Utills.profan(name) && (name != null)
                && ((!name.equals("")) || (!name.equals(" ")))) {

            bool = true;
            player.setName(Utills.filter(name)); //Error is here

        }
        else {

            bool = false;

        }

    } while (bool == false);

    player.Height = getUsrHeight();

    System.out.print("Please select your stats. ");

    do {

        System.out.println("Points Remaining: " + points);

        switch (i) {

        case 0:

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of points to alot to "
                    + "Strength.\n Min:1 Max:18");

            str = sc.nextInt();
            if ((str >= 1) && (str <= 18) && (str <= points) &&
                    ((points - str) >= 5)) {

                points -= str;
                i++;

            }
            break;

        case 1:

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of points to alot to "
                    + "Dexterity.\n Min:1 Max:18");

            dex = sc.nextInt();
            if ((dex >= 1) && (dex <= 18) && (dex <= points) &&
                    ((points - dex) >= 4)) {

                points -= dex;
                i++;

            }
            break;

        case 2:

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of points to alot to "
                    + "Endurance.\n Min:1 Max:18");

            end = sc.nextInt();
            if ((end >= 1) && (end <= 18) && (end <= points) &&
                    ((points - end) >= 3)) {

                points -= end;
                i++;

            }
            break;

        case 3:

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of points to alot to "
                    + "Inteligence.\n Min:1 Max:18");

            INT = sc.nextInt();
            if ((INT >= 1) && (INT <= 18) && (INT <= points) &&
                    ((points - INT) >= 2)) {

                points -= INT;
                i++;

            }
            break;

        case 4:

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of points to alot to "
                    + "Luck.\n Min:1 Max:18");

            lck = sc.nextInt();
            if ((lck >= 1) && (lck <= 18) && (lck <= points) &&
                    ((points - lck) >= 1)) {

                points -= lck;
                i++;

            }
            break;

        case 5:

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of points to alot to "
                    + "Charisma.\n Min:1 Max:18");

            cha = sc.nextInt();
            if ((cha >= 1) && (cha <= 18) && (cha <= points)) {

                points -= cha;
                i++;

            }
            break;

        case 6:

            int[] stats = {str, dex, end, INT, lck, cha};

            player.setStats(stats);
            cont = false;
            break;

        }

    }while (cont);


    return player;

}
```

The Error here comes from the Utills.filter(name):

```
public static String filter(String name) {

    //Variables
    String[] Name = name.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder endStr = new StringBuilder();

    char temp;

    int i = 0;

    //Sorting
    for(String w: Name) {

        sb.append(w);

        temp = Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(0)); //And Error is here
        sb.setCharAt(0, temp);

        if(i >= 1) {

            endStr.append(" " + sb.toString());

        }
        else {

            endStr.append(sb);

        }

        i++;
        empty(sb);

    }


    return endStr.toString();

}
```

I would be greatfull for any help

Comment: The error message should tell you what line the error is on.  Please let us know what it is (and _show_ us which line it is; don't just tell us the line number, because we won't be able to figure out which line that is.  Best is to edit your question and add a comment to your code indicating what line the error message is referring to).

Comment: What is the value of `name`? If the error is in `filter()`, then the other code has no meaning to your question, and is just noise. The relevant part is the value causing the error and the line where the error occurs.

Comment: Without knowing which line the error is on, it's hard to tell.  But my guess would be that `w` may be an empty string.

Comment: Or has leading space.

Comment: Added comments to show where error is coming from

Comment: Also, value of name is determined by the user, "sc" is a static scanner object

Comment: But what is the value of `name` when the error occurs? What input is causing your problem?

Comment: It throws an error before I can even enter any input

Comment: What do you mean? You said the error comes on a lines after the `name = sc.nextLine()` statement, which will stop and wait for input. You even have a print statement right after. Or did you use `sc` before, e.g. calling `nextInt()`?

Comment: Define before. The error occurs after that statement, but I do not get a chance to enter anything, it doesn't wait.

Comment: The Submited solution has solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this:

```
if (Utills.profan(name) && (name != null)
            && ((!name.equals("")) || (!name.equals(" "))))
```

It should probably be

```
if (Utills.profan(name) && (name != null)
            && !name.equals("") && !name.equals(" "))
```

or even

```
if (Utills.profan(name) && (name != null)
            && !name.trim().isEmpty())
```

If you still don't see what problem I mean, the check `((!name.equals("")) || (!name.equals(" ")))` will always be `true`, because `name` is always either not `""` or not `" "`.